# Print Debug statement in INFORMIX

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, informix

I'm using SQL Stored Procedure on an INFORMIX Database.
While I generate DEBUG file using

```
SET DEBUG FILE TO
```

I need to print Debug statement.
eg: Print count of rows in Temporary table.

One of the method could be

```
RAISERROR('your message here!!!',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

But I'm not sure how to print count of a table using this **`RAISE ERROR`** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlca.sqlerrd[3] contains the number of rows processed in the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps:

```
DEFINE temp_count INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO temp_count FROM TempTable;

TRACE 'Count of rows in TempTable is ', temp_count;
```

The only thing to check is whether you can build up a message piecewise as in the TRACE statement.  If not, then you can build the string before you supply it to TRACE:

```
DEFINE trace_message VARCHAR(255);
LET trace_message = 'Count of rows in TempTable = ' || temp_count;
TRACE trace_message;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DEBUG FILE TO '/tmp/foo.trace';
    TRACE OFF;
    TRACE ON;
```

Use above 3 statements to print debug your stored procedure.